# Symfony my Controller::updateAction() requires that you provide a value for the "$name" argument

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, routes, updates

Using Symfony 2, I have this error when I try to **pass an argument/variable**:

```
Controller "MyBundle\Controller\ManageController::updateAction()" 
requires that you provide a value for the "$name" argument (because there is 
no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

this the **entity/model** `Parcs`:

```
namespace MyBundle\DatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Parcsimmobilier
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="parcs")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Parcs
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
```

First, I have a twig, which can allow users to **modify/update** a Parc, I'm using JavaScript to allow the `select tag` *in html* to display a form in another **route/twig** when a choice is made, this is the code for **choose the parcs** users would like to update:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Which Parcs would you like to update ?</label>
  <form action="{{ path('UpdateParcs_form' , {'name':'parcs.name'}) }}" method="GET">
    <select class="form-control" id="selectpicker">
      <option disabled selected> select your parc </option>
      {% for parcsimmobilier in parc %}
        <option value="parc"><strong>{{ parcs.name}}</strong></option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is the **JavaScript** code which allow me to redirect users after a choice on the other route which displaying the **update form**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectpicker').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

And now the twig to who **display the form to update** the chosen parc:

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ path('updateParcs_process') }}" method="POST">
      <div>
      {{ form_label(form.name, "change the name of the parc", {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        <div>
          {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

So when I submit on my update Button, I have the error:

> Controller "MyBundle\Controller\ManageController::updateAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$name" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

This is my **controller** code with the **update action**:

```
public function updateAction($name) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $parc = $em->getRepository('MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Parcs')->find($name);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ParcsType(), $parc);

    $request = $this->get('request');

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid())) {

            $form->bind($request);
            $parc = $form->getData();
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index_parcs'));
        }

    //retourner le formulaire d'ajout si c'est invalide
    else {
            return $this->render('MySpaceManageBundle:Parcs:updateParcs.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'parc' => $parc, 'name' => $name));
         }
}
```

This is the routing file for my routes:

```
# index for management
index_Parcs:
    path:     /manageparcs
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceManageBundle:Manage:indexParcs }
    requirements:
    methods: GET

# route for display the form after the select choice
updateParcs_form:
    path:     /manageparcs/update/form/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceManageBundle:Manage:update }
    requirements:
    methods: GET

# route for processing form with update
updateParcs_process:
    path:     /manageparcs/update/form/success
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceManageBundle:Manage:update }
    requirements:
    methods: POST
```

My questions are these:
Why do I have this error? How can I fix it?
And how can I **update** correctly my entity/model with this **updateAction()**. How can I **pass** the **arguments** by a **route** in Symfony.

Comment: Sometimes `name` is used, sometimes `nom` is used. Doesn't match...

Comment: @Paziツ, sorry, my mistake when I paste my code. I'm a french developper, I translate my functions and names in order to find an issue on stackoverflow. I'll edit my code.

Comment: updateAction($name = null) will take care of the error message.  However, having two different routes cal the same action with different parameters is a bit iffy.  I would use two actions.  And be aware that you can also add default values directly to the routes.

Comment: @Cerad, I try your solution and I have this error: `The identifier id is missing for a query of MySpace\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Parcs`

Comment: Yep.  You need to spend some time looking at the difference between find and findBy.

Comment: @Cerad, even if I use FindBy, and so an array, the update doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updateParcs_form:
    path:     /manageparcs/update/form/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceManageBundle:Manage:update }
    requirements:
    methods: GET

# route for processing form with update
updateParcs_process:
    path:     /manageparcs/update/form/success
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceManageBundle:Manage:update }
    requirements:
    methods: POST
```

Your second route doesn't specify a name parameter as the first one does.
The cause is that the method is expecting the argument, but based on this configuration none will be provided.

Unless you want to create another action for the POST request, you will need to add the name to the POST URI.

```
path:     /manageparcs/update/form/{name}/success
```

And you will need to generate the URI with this parameter.

Comment: He passes name parameter in POST-request.

Comment: @Flosculus, I no longer have the error `Controller "MyBundle\Controller\ManageController::updateAction()" ... non optional argument after this one).` However, the update doesn't match. indeed, I would like to change the name of a parc, I have updated my code like in your suggestion, but if I input text to change mail in my form, It does not update the name of the selected parcs before in my select tag

Comment: More, I just realize that in my url, when I change my code in my route file like you suggest me, there is not the name of my selected name field like that `localhost/manageparcs/update/form/nameOfMyparc`, I have the parameter parcs.name like that `localhost/manageparcs/update/form/parcs.name?`. I think, I forgot something, like the fact that the select have to select the name field in my model/entity. (Sorry I am a little confuse)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right things except you have `$nom` as parameter in your controller but `name` in your routing configuration. According to other files it will be easy to change only configuration:

Change `name` in `routing.yml` to `nom`:

```
updateParcs_form:
path:     /manageparcs/update/form/{nom}
defaults: { _controller: MySpaceManageBundle:Manage:update }
requirements:
methods: GET
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake when I paste my code. as a french developper, when I posted my question, I translate into english for a better comprehension on this website. I forget some field "nom", now I've updated my code. Sorry, really.